# How to read javascript BLOB data sent over websocket on java websocket server

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, blob

I am trying to upload a picture file on my webpage through javascript as a BLOB type of file, then send that file to my java websocket server to store the file on the server used for the webpage.

My code on the websocker server java side is as to read the BLOB data and write the file is as follows,

```
public void testMethod(final WebMessage message){
    ByteBuffer b = null;
    try {
        b = message.getByteBufferArg(0);
    } catch (WebMessageException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    File file = new File("/user/Desktop/pic.jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        stream.write(b.array());
        logger.info("done writing file");
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.trace(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then when I try to open the picture it says `Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00)`.

Basically I would like to know then how I can read this BLOB data that was sent to my websocket server, and how can I write this data out to a useable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only way to read from a Blob is using a FileReader (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), once you've read the data from a blob (I would just read in a BinaryArray - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString)  You can then directly just send that to your file in an output stream.

From the documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob:

> Example for extracting data from a Blob
>
> The only way to read content from a Blob is to use a FileReader. The following code reads the content of a Blob as a typed array.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
   // reader.result contains the contents of blob as a typed array
});
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

> By using other methods of FileReader, it is possible to read the contents of a Blob as a string or a data URL.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to not send the data as a BLOB from the javascript side, you need to read the data into some readable format. In this case I use the `FileReader` API to read the BLOB data as a `dataurl`. After it is read using that method, the data is in `base64` readable format and can be sent over the websocket and written out to a file on the other side after the base64 String is decoded.